# Prevent type conversion in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

I am currently learning JavaScript. I used to work with statically typed languages, so, naturally, I decided to start with TypeScript instead of JS. TypeScript is nice and it solves a lot of problems JS has, but this "weak typing" really triggers me.

It doesn't feel right that I can get away with this:

```
let int: number = 42
let str: string = "69"

console.log(int + str)
```

Is there a way to prevent this type of conversion from happening even in the TypeScript? I want to get an error when add `string` to an `integer`.

Comment: You'll get an error as soon as you try to use the result in a place where (only) a number is expected. Otherwise, something like `"the answer is "+42+"!"` is perfectly valid and normal code, TypeScript won't complain about it.

Comment: @Bergi It's _valid_ yes, but because it invokes JS' type-juggling it's also _undesirable_.

Comment: @Bergi That is correct, but OP is asking how to disallow implicit number->string type casting.

Comment: What you're asking for was requested back in 2016 and is still open: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7989

Comment: @Dai What I'm saying is that [there won't be such an option](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7989#issuecomment-207898540) because its standard, desirable usage

Comment: @Bergi, hopefully you saw the comment just [below that](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7989#issuecomment-208048488). Even though it's standard, but mainly "because JavaScript does it", it may not be that desirable.

Comment: I’m guessing eslint has something

Comment: @DanielA.White [TypeScript-ESLint's `restrict-plus-operands`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/restrict-plus-operands.md)

Comment: @tevemadar No, it's not desirable "because JS does it", it'd desirable because it's simpler and more convenient to write `\`the answer is ${42}!\`` than `\`the answer is ${String(42)}!\``

Comment: @Bergi, those are not mutually exclusive. Like take a Python console and try `"a"+42` and `f"a{42}"` in it. The first one will fail, the second one will work.

Comment: @Dai To be specific, it is undesirable by people who don't like Javascript. But for people who actually love the language it leads to cleaner and more readable code. If javascript is not for you, you have other options that compiles to javascript/wasm like Rust or Dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no rule in TypeScript that would prevent your doing that; the result of the expression `int + str` is `string`.

Now, if you tried to assign that to a variable of type `number`, that would fail:

```typescript
let int: number = 42
let str: string = "69"

let result: number = int + str;
//  ^ error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
```

---

Note that this has little to do with loose typing; many strongly-typed languages such as Java and C# do exactly the same thing, implicitly convert the number to a string when using `+` in that way. [Java example](https://ideone.com/EaC2sa) | [C# example](https://ideone.com/11wVS9). Granted JavaScript takes this ridiculously far, but that's more about the early ethos in the language having been to prefer conversion over throwing errors. (Both probably stem from the same underlying goal, though, which was to make the language really accommodating — too much so, we now know. :-) )

Comment: "Note that this has little to do with loose typing; many strongly-typed languages such as Java and C# do exactly the same thing, implicitly convert the number to a string when using + in that way" - yes, but C# _et al._ doesn't [do all this](https://javascriptwtf.com/).

Comment: Language aside, I think the "issue" is the "overloaded" `+` operator. If I remember correctly, there were some proposals for custom operator overloading in JS or TS?

LE: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-operator-overloading this is the only reference I found so far.

Comment: @Dai - Indeed, JavaScript's type conversion is ... quite wild. :-)

Comment: @Dai C# does many of those things as well

Comment: To make it clearer: once you use the `+` operator, you have to understand how it works and that it does indeed try to do type coercion behind the scenes. Whether this default behavior makes sense or not, it's up to the reader (writer?).

Answer (score 0):

Typescript as noted above doesn’t have this but Eslint does: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-implicit-coercion and https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/restrict-plus-operands.md